# How do I print the value of a Task in elm-repl?

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, elm

Let's say I've created a simple task in `elm-repl`, like:

```
> forty = Task.succeed 40 
<task> : Task.Task a number
```

How do I take my `forty` and... use it? I can convert the `Task` into a `Cmd` via:

```
> Task.perform (\x -> Nothing) (\a -> Just a) forty
{ type = "leaf", home = "Task", value = T <task> }
    : Platform.Cmd.Cmd (Maybe.Maybe Float)
```

... but I'm not sure if this takes me closer to my goal, since I don't know how to "force" the command (e.g. to print out its value to the screen).

Comment: Aside from inspecting the value of a task, is there a specific goal you are trying to achieve _outside_ of the REPL?

Comment: No - I'm specifically trying to understand the language by running some code and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 6):

The Elm REPL does not yet allow for execution of Tasks. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-repl/issues/77) for this feature request.

Comment: Thanks! Can you describe a good debugging work flowers that would allow me to work with Tasks outside and the REPL, then, given these limitations?

Comment: Since Elm is a pure functional language, you don't really need to perform tasks for testing since you are guaranteed the same output for the same input. You can "mock" any functions simply by calling them in your unit tests. Don't write tests for Tasks, test your `update` functions.