# Inspecting variables in Elm

Tags: types, command, message, elm, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to understand how Elm type system works. Coming from an imperative programming background, i'm used to take advantage of a debbuger with step and breakpoints to figure out what's happening. But apparently that is not the functionnal way.

Using the REPL to figure out trivial exemples is easy, but it gets way more complicated with something like Http.get for exemple.

Here is what i have tried :

Apparently I have to define a certain custom type for the message to be returned by the runtime when the HTTP request has been done :

`> type Message = Done (Result Http.Error String)`

Now I'm storing the result of the Http.get in some variable :

`> test = Http.get { url = "http://192.168.1.10:3000/site", expect = Http.expectString Done }`

Then i'd like to see what's inside `test` :

```
> test
<internals> : Cmd Message
```

If i understood correctly, `test` seems to have the expected type and is now some command i can somehow send to the Elm runtime.

Now here is what i want to do :

1 - print what's inside the `Message` payload of my `test` command.

2 - send the command to the runtime and fetch the result somehow (from the REPL)

3 - print what's inside the `Message` i'm supposed to get back from the runtime.

Is it possible ? Does it make sense ?
If not, how am I supposed to take a look at whats happening behind the apparent magic in order to really understand Elm, especially the rather cryptic type annotations ?

Bonus question :
`Http.get` has the following definition :

```
get :
    { url : String
    , expect : Expect msg
    }
    -> Cmd msg
```

Do `msg` have to be a custom type ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do `msg` have to be a custom type ?

No. It can be any type, so for instance that could just as well be `String` for instance.

Now to the meat of the question: In the REPL, you can evaluate Elm *expressions* - and Elm as such is a *pure* language, which means it cannot execute (almost) any effects, such as HTTP requests.

However, there is a special kind of value in Elm called a `Cmd`, that if handed over to the `Program` value will ask the runtime to execute some effect on your behalf. For this to work, you must designate that `Program` value your application entry point by naming it `main`.

This cannot be done in the REPL; hence the Elm REPL cannot execute `Cmd`s.

---

So in order to play with `Cmd`, you'll need to create an Elm application and run it in the browser.

Something like this:

```
import Browser 
import Html


main = Browser.element   
    { init = \() -> ({}, test) -- ask the runtime for your message
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none 
    , view = \_ -> Html.text "Hello world!"
    }

update msg model =
    case msg of
        Done result ->
            let 
                _ = Debug.log "HTTP request completed" result

            in
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

---

> 1 - print what's inside the Message payload of my test command.

Your `test` command has no Message payload to print. The type parameter `Cmd Message` doesn't mean that the value somehow "contains" the `Message` type, it just asserts a certain kind of relationship between the types. In this case a future relationship, which you can think of as a "Command that in the future may produce a `Message` type of value".

You could think of the `Cmd` type implemented something like this (it's not, but could be):

```
type Cmd msg
    = NoCmd
    | HTTP Method Url (Response -> msg)
    | Sleep Duration (() -> msg)
    ...
```

Comment: It works indeed : i can see what i fetched with Http.get in the browser console. Thanks.

Comment: Similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958187/how-do-i-print-the-value-of-a-task-in-elm-repl